# Inproper jquery linking asp.net razor mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/638674/Full-calendar-A-complete-web-diary-system-for-jQue

to add a calender to my website (asp.net mvc)

I'm new to mvc and I have this view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MenuPlanner";
}

@section scripts{
@Scripts.Render(@Url.Content("~/bundles/jqueryui"))
@Scripts.Render(@Url.Content("~/bundles/jquery"))
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var sourceFullView = { url: '/Home/GetDiaryEvents/' };
            var sourceSummaryView = { url: '/Home/GetDiarySummary/' };
            var CalLoading = true;

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                editable: true,
                allDaySlot: false,
                selectable: true,
                slotMinutes: 15,
                events: '/Home/GetDiaryEvents/',
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    alert('You clicked on event id: ' + calEvent.id
                        + "\nSpecial ID: " + calEvent.someKey
                        + "\nAnd the title is: " + calEvent.title);

                },

                eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
                    if (confirm("Confirm move?")) {
                        UpdateEvent(event.id, event.start);
                    }
                    else {
                        revertFunc();
                    }
                },

                eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {

                    if (confirm("Confirm change appointment length?")) {
                        UpdateEvent(event.id, event.start, event.end);
                    }
                    else {
                        revertFunc();
                    }
                },



                dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                    $('#eventTitle').val("");
                    $('#eventDate').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
                    $('#eventTime').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'HH:mm'));
                    ShowEventPopup(date);
                },

                viewRender: function (view, element) {

                    if (!CalLoading) {
                        if (view.name == 'month') {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceFullView);
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceFullView);
                        }
                    }
                }

            });

            CalLoading = false;


        });

        $('#btnInit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/Init",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == 'True') {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        alert('Database populated! ');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Error, could not populate database!');
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $('#btnPopupCancel').click(function () {
            ClearPopupFormValues();
            $('#popupEventForm').hide();
        });

        $('#btnPopupSave').click(function () {

            $('#popupEventForm').hide();

            var dataRow = {
                'Title': $('#eventTitle').val(),
                'NewEventDate': $('#eventDate').val(),
                'NewEventTime': $('#eventTime').val(),
                'NewEventDuration': $('#eventDuration').val()
            }

            ClearPopupFormValues();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/SaveEvent",
                data: dataRow,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == 'True') {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        alert('New event saved!');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Error, could not save event!');
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        function ShowEventPopup(date) {
            ClearPopupFormValues();
            $('#popupEventForm').show();
            $('#eventTitle').focus();
        }

        function ClearPopupFormValues() {
            $('#eventID').val("");
            $('#eventTitle').val("");
            $('#eventDateTime').val("");
            $('#eventDuration').val("");
        }

        function UpdateEvent(EventID, EventStart, EventEnd) {

            var dataRow = {
                'ID': EventID,
                'NewEventStart': EventStart,
                'NewEventEnd': EventEnd
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/UpdateEvent",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(dataRow)
            });
        }

</script>


}


<div class="container">

    <div>
        <a href="#" id="btnInit" class="btn btn-secondary">Initialise database!</a>
    </div>

    <div id='calendar' style="width:65%"></div>

</div>


<div id="popupEventForm" class="modal hide" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header"><h3>Add new event</h3></div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="EventForm" class="well">
            <input type="hidden" id="eventID">
            <label>Event title</label>
            <input type="text" id="eventTitle" placeholder="Title here"><br />
            <label>Scheduled date</label>
            <input type="text" id="eventDate"><br />
            <label>Scheduled time</label>
            <input type="text" id="eventTime"><br />
            <label>Appointment length (minutes)</label>
            <input type="text" id="eventDuration" placeholder="15"><br />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="btnPopupCancel" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" id="btnPopupSave" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Save event</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is that I am getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

at this line:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
```

and I have no idea why.

Any ideas please?

Comment: I think it can not find fullCalendar function. Make sure you imported all the plugins and libriries where this function is defined.

Comment: Change the order of your scripts so that jquery is included before jqueryui.

Answer (score 0):

For **FullCalendar**, you need to have the libraries loaded.  You either need to create a new bundle, or you have to load them in the page.  From the **FullCalendar** [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/), you need these scripts loaded.

```
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

If you want to go the bundling route:

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fullcalendar").Include(
                "~/Scripts/moment.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"));
```

**HTML**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcalendar")
```